# Painting on a mesh in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh

i'm trying to draw paint on a mesh using some kind of brush, i found a brush online but it doesn't support the latest three.js version. I've done a lot of google searching but i can't seem to find any usefull information anywhere. the brush i found: [brush.js](http://pastebin.com/xVCrqM8Q) (pastebin because its quite a big amount of code).

could anyone explain the concept of painting on a mesh to me using either code snippets or reference links?

Comment: I think that could be done with raycasting + decals creation.

Comment: @mlkn do the decals actually become part of the mesh? as in if i export the mesh, the decals ill be exported aswell?

Comment: No, [decals](https://github.com/mlknz/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/geometries/DecalGeometry.js) create separate shape. Actually, it should be possible to draw on texture since you know uv's from raycasting.

Comment: Reviving an ancient thread.. I wrote this over the last couple days:

https://manthrax.github.io/monkeypaint/index.html?1